# magento incorrect 404 not found url key for specific store view

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0

we have two store views (english and spanish) in our magento ce 1.8.1.0 site, for the english store view home product links are working just fine, but in the spanish store view the url is adding "//storecode" in the link, resulting 404 not found page, we have set to "no" admin>general>web>Add Store Code to Urls ; other data is that out root category name is the name that it's being added after the "//" in  the product link.

any ideas what could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

in order to solve this we had to delete and re-add the store, found no other solution.